# How can I get the url of my files uploaded from ec2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ng-file-upload

I have used HTML to upload a file to a web location.

```
<input name="fileInput" type="file" fileinput="files" ngf-select
       ng-model="picFile1 "accept="image/*" NGF-max-size="2MB"required
       ngf-model-invalid="error file">
```

I am using AngularJS front-end and Java back-end for the platform. This system is running on Amazon EC2 setup.
I want to download this file on another web by using .

```
<form name="contractForm">  
    <a href="**url**" download="Contract.pdf">Contract</a>
</form>
```

So I need to get a specific file path and put this URL in href attribute. My question is how can I get it? This should be back-end work, but I want to learn that

Comment: From where are you downloading the files? From an Amazon S3 bucket, or from an Amazon EC2 instance?

Comment: Be specific on what you're trying to ask. This question is vague.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean you are uploading images to s3 bucket in AWS , In this Case you can get the download path of image by creating a path which will include 
aws s3 path + bucketname + imageName
Here imageName can be anything which you want (eg. Timestamp) this you can save in database and than use this path to download the same images.